# Built-in function to get sub-series from a series?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, data-visualization

I use [Chart WindowsForms Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd489237.aspx) (`System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` namespace)'s [Series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series?view=netframework-4.7.2).

I can get sub-series by coding it manually but is there any built-in function to get sub-series from a series of specified range ?
(Pseudo-code like below)

```
Series subseries = bigseries.Point.CopyTo(BeginIndex , EndIndex);
```

I need to work with multiple series (dynamically generated) and get sub-series of them for further data processing. Kindly suggest if there is. This will save much effort.

Comment: What is `bigseries`? And what has Python to do with this (judging the [tag:series] tag)?

Comment: I'm working in MS chart and dealing with multiple series to display.

Comment: why do you don't explain that? We aren't in your head to know it! And don't use tags in the title (C# ;.NET)

Comment: He is talking about `Chart.Series` https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd456769.aspx

Comment: @Serge I'm extremely sorry. I didn't know winform. Series is different from Series.

Comment: there is no need to know winform to clearly explain your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried but maybe this works:

```
Series subSeries = new Series();
bigSeries.Points
    .Skip(BeginIndex)
    .Take(EndIndex - BeginIndex)
    .ToList().ForEach(subSeries.Points.Add);
```

Comment: It's working for single series. I'm sure this will work for multiple Series. I will update you soon.

Comment: I have modified the code and its working for multiple series dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Skip` and `Take` methods for picking items dynamically from a list.

```
var listDemo = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
var beginIndex = 2;
var endIndex = 2;
var result = listDemo.Skip(beginIndex).Take(endIndex).ToList();
```

Comment: I m working on `Series` not on `List`.

Comment: @user2587 Nobody knows what `Series` is except you.

Comment: @spender I'm talking about Series in winform. If there is some other Series, my mistake I wasn't aware about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the partial code for getting sub-series from multiple series and displaying on the chart. Thanks @Tim Schmelter, @Serge and others for their valuable answers and comments.

```
List<Series> ListSeries = new List<Series>();

       foreach(Series series in chart1.Series)
        {
            Series subSeries = new Series();
            series.Points.Skip(BeginIndex).Take(EndIndex - BeginIndex).ToList().ForEach(subSeries.Points.Add);
            ListSeries.Add(subSeries);
        }

        chart1.Series.Clear();

        foreach (Series series in ListSeries)
        {
            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series.Add(series);
        }
    }
```